# Python 2.7: update element in a list

Tags: python, list

I would like to update an element from a list.

This is my kind of list:

```
list= ["toto", "stack" , "element_to_update", "overflow"]
```

I want to update this list when `"toto"` and `"stack"` found as `element[0]` and `element[1]` to have my list updated (and concatenate with existing `element[2]`)

The list that I want at the end:

```
list=["toto", "stack", "element_to_update_is_updated", "overflow"]
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: and what you try?what trouble do you have?

Comment: You should explain a Little bit more what you wanna

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
l = ["toto", "stack", "element_to_update", "overflow"]
if l[:2] == ['toto','stack']:
    l[2] += '_is_updated'
```

And now:

```
print(l)
```

Is:

```
['toto', 'stack', 'element_to_update_is_updated', 'overflow']
```